# Is "discover him from another side" idiomatic?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Is it okay to say "to discover a person from another side" meaning "to find out something new about a person"?

Google returns zero results for ["discover him from another side"](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&sxsrf=ALeKk003BNRPIl3y7TnS1njas70-EYcxIQ%3A1593102249783&ei=qc_0XsGmL7CwmAX454igBg&q=%22discover%20him%20from%20another%20side%22&oq=%22discover%20him%20from%20another%20side%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQDDoFCCEQoAE6BAghEApQ7OYUWLP4FGDahhVoAHAAeACAAXqIAf8EkgEEMTIuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiBn8GtsJ3qAhUwGKYKHfgzAmQQ4dUDCAw)

Will it be idiomatic in English to say that?

For example,

> Had I had one more month, I might have **discovered Peter from another
> side**. But, sadly, as I had only as much time as I had, I am forced to
> state here that all I know about him is that he is a rather lukewarm
> player on a team showing little-to-zero enthusiasm in the project.

Comment: It is more usual to say "I might have discovered another side of/to Peter."

Comment: I cannot decide whether it is genuinely old-fashioned or an ill-advised attempt at seeming old-fashioned.

Comment: @AntonSherwood - I can't understand what you mean. Can you, please, elaborate.

Comment: The phrase is odd, in a way suggesting (at least to my intuition) that it might have been written more than a hundred years ago.  The use of *zero*, on the other hand, is much more modern than the rest of the passage.  Therefore I suspect an intentional archaism.

Comment: @AntonSherwood - What is intentional archaism? It's just that that phrase is very common in my first language, but I am not sure if it's also common in English. There is nothing intentional here.

Comment: Oh, the example sentence is your own translation of a sentence from your own language?  I thought you had found it in a book in English.

Comment: One idiomatic expression in English is "to see another side of".  Another idiomatic expression is "little to no".  Obviously, the semantics remain similar to your literal translations, but a few web searches with variations on those phrasings might help you to discover the more common colocations and how they look in their usual contexts.

Answer (score 1):

There are some commonly used  phrases for this:

> - gotten to know another side of [...]
> - seen another side of [...]

You could write,

> Had I had one more month, I might have seen another side of Peter.

...or...

> Had I had one more month, I might have gotten to know Peter a little better.

As a side note, I reccomend that you not share your opinions about Peter with anyone else. Your thoughts are downright cruel.

> Peter is a rather lukewarm player on a team which shows little-to-no enthusiasm in the project.

That is not nice at all.

Also, try to avoid having more than 2 or 3 clauses inside of the same sentence.

> 1. But
> 2. sadly.
> 3. as I had only as much time as I had.
> 4. I am forced to state here that
> 5. All I know is that

That is too many optional clauses. Optional clauses such as "***I am forced to state here***" fail to add any additional information.

Comment: "*I reccomend that you not share your opinions about Peter with anyone else. Your thoughts are downright cruel*" - In fact, this recommendation of yours is rather cruel. You know nothing about who I shared my opinions about Peter with. They were all fine and even thankful to me afterwards. Saying "don't share that with anyone else" is rather presumptuous on your part..

Comment: How is "but" a clause???

Comment: "*Optional clauses such as "I am forced to state here" fail to add any additional information*" - It informs the reader of the fact that what I am about to state regarding Peter is something that I wouldn't want to state otherwise had it not been for this particular circumstance (lack of time spent with Peter).